# How to set one property before typescript constructor runs

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor

Some JavaScript libraries and frameworks provide the possibility of early *binding* of properties, so that the developers has the possibility to use that *bound* properties even in constructors. I need to make the same hack for tests.

The main problem is that that *bind* property is used in constructor and I cannot instantiate the controller for covering with tests.

The constructor of the class must not be changed (adding new parameters or something) because the logic of creation the class is managed by the framework and I do not want to add any optional/not optional parameters to the class' constructor.

I've tried something like that. No luck, because I am missing something.

```
function createMyController(bindProperty, ...controllerArgs) {
        let myController = Object.create(MyController);
        myController.bindProperty = bindProperty;
        MyController.constructor.apply(myController, [...controllerArgs]);
        // post creation assignments or modifications
        return myController;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of a binding is called pre-binding and it was used, for example, in angularjs (angular 1). The idea behind this pre-binding is to initiate some properties before the constructor function is called.

It may be solved by first initiating the object of some type. Then binding all the needed values. And finally calling the constructor itself.

```
function createMyController(bindProperty, ...controllerArgs) {
    let myController = Object.create(MyController.prototype);
    myController.bindProperty = bindProperty;
    MyController.call(myController, ...controllerArgs);
    // post creation assignments or modifications
    return myController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript constructors allow the use of [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) that do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am afraid I may not change the constructor's parameters